# Docker/Rails - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, permission-denied

I am getting a permission error when I try to get the container up by using `docker-compose up -d` Running this on macOS worked fine, tried to build the application on a new machine (Ubuntu), but it didnt work.

```
Exiting
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:433:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/api/limpar/current/tmp/pids/server.pid (Errno::EACCES)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV NODE_VERSION 12
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV INSTALL_PATH /home/api/limpar/current

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs postgresql-client yarn build-essential vim

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY . $INSTALL_PATH

RUN rm -rf tmp

RUN useradd -Ms /bin/bash api -u 1001
RUN chown -R api:api /home/api /usr/local/bundle
USER api


EXPOSE 3000
CMD rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

docker build runs with no failures.
Any missing points on Dockerfile, regarding user permissions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running the container?  (You mention Compose; are there `volumes:` overwriting what the image has installed in `/home/api`?)

Comment: It worked @DavidMaze! If you would like it submit it as an answer, I will take it :)
for reference, changed the volume on docker-compose.yml file to `./:/home/limpar-api/limpar/current` (as long as paths differ)